# run rails applicaton after capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

**Deploying rails app throw Capistrano first time**:  I deployed my rails app on another machine (server)

**File structure for rails app**  `## this is my server`

```
akshay@akshay:/var/www/model_demo$ ls
current  releases  repo  revisions.log  shared

cap -T ## showing a lots of rake task
```

like

`cap deploy:migrate    # Runs rake db:migrate if migrations are set`

If I run this task it is not working saying

```
Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage you have defined.
```

But when I run

```
cap production deploy  # It works
```

Among all the listed task only `cap production deploy`

**1:** what exactly going on under the hood?

**2:** How might i run rake task which is provided by cap?

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano recepies are meant to run on local system.
Run it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I catch my mistake. And as  I followed [Railscasts Capistrano screencasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks),  [stackoverflow Capistrano Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/capistrano/info) and [deploying-rails-apps-to-a-vps-with-capistrano-v3](http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/01/deploying-rails-apps-to-a-vps-with-capistrano-v3/).

**`As all cap tasks run locally`**.

`cap production deploy:migrate` **`# Worked for me`**

Thanks to @maxd !!!