# Capistrano deploy configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, bitbucket, capistrano3

Help please to configure capistrano for deployment.
I have ssh:

- user: User
- host: 8.8.8.8:6554
- pass: 123

Then i have bitbucket repository git@bitbucket.org:somerepo/code.git

- user: Repouser@gmail.com
- pass: repopass

I am just need to deploy code from default branch to User@8.8.8.8:8888:/public_html/test/ . On local machine i have ssh key, that allows me to connect without password. But capistrano didn't connect.

There is my config:

```
lock '3.3.5'
set :application, 'App'
set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:somerepo/code.git'
set :scm_passphrase, ""
set :scm_user, "Repouser@gmail.com"
set :user, 'User'
set :deploy_to, '/public_html/test'
set :app_dir, "/public_html/test"
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
role :web, '8.8.8.8:6554'

namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
    end
  end
end
```

Error:

> connection closed by remote host
>   ** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
>   ** Execute deploy:failed

Comment: Please help someone. I need to deploy this today.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** in Gemfile

```
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rails'
```

**Step 2:** bundle

**Step 3:** `cap install` ## it will generate set of file

**Step 4:** go in `Capfile` and paste the following code ## this file will be parallel to your rails application

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**Step 5:** Config/deploy.rb that will be common to both **ENV**

**This file will be shared/common across the application environment**

```
    set :application, 'your_app'  ## keep in mind that your app dir name will be your_app  
    set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:somerepo/code.git'
    set :branch, 'master'
    set :use_sudo, true
    set :deploy_to, '/public_html/test'
    set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml')
    set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('bin', 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

**Step6:** **Lets create ENV specific file for now For production Environment**

`config/deploy/production.rb`  ## this file will be generate by `cap install` command that you did earlier no need for this time

do comment all the code except this

```
role :app, %w{8.8.8.8:6554}
set :ssh_options, {
                user: 'User'
            }
```

**Step 6:** now do `ssh to your server` `ssh User@8.8.8.8:6554`
now it will ask for the password ... `give password`

**Step 7:** now by default  your app will go `/var/www/app` and here you need to create the folder accordingly But in your case as you `set :deploy_to, '/public_html/test'`   # make sure Dir name is followed by / 'Forward slash' this mistake i did many times

```
sudo mkdir -p /public_html
sudo mkdir -p /public_html/test
sudo chown User:User /public_html/test # `chown` will change the owner ship so that `User` user can `**Read/Write**` 
umask 0002
mkdir /public_html/test/releases ## these are convention 
mkdir /public_html/test/shared ## these are convention 
sudo chown User:User public_html/test/releases
sudo chown User:User public_html/test/shared
mkdir .ssh
chmod .ssh 007
ssh-keygen -t rsa
and follow the step  ## this will generate ssh key 
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Now add this key to your repo's go to => setting => deployment keys Button => click on that and **add `Key`**. Put the **label** name any thing you want and paste the `ssh key` here.

**That it** from **server** side

**Step8:** Now you need to add your ssh key to server 
For that do `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` if you have `rsa` key other wise generate rsa key it is very easy to crate

**Step 9:** Login to your server using ssh

```
`vi .ssh/authorized_keys` and paste your local machine rsa key
```

save and exit

**Step 10 :** `cap -T`  ## list out all the task

**step 11:** `cap production deploy:check`

It will throw an error because database.yml file is not there

For that `vi /public_html/test/shared/config/database.yml`

```
    development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: testdb_cap
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

**save and exit**

Do again `cap production deploy:check`

This time would not throw any error

**Step 12:**

```
 cap production deploy
```

And That's it

Check this also [ruby rake task after deploymewnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805808/run-rails-applicaton-after-capistrano-deployment)